# Possible to draw an overlay screen from host over a full screen VM guest?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, vmware, vmware-player

I've tried this in the past with qt top most windows etc but no luck. Anyone know if this is even possible. Appreciate the help thank you!

Comment: What has got VMWare to do with this?

Comment: I want the software to run on the host but be displayed as an overlayed window/hud on a vmware workstation guest in full-screen. Thank you for response!

Comment: You can make the window opaque by calling `setWindowOpacity()`, I believe it's a `QWidget` method. Another method you can play with is `setAttribute()` with `Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground`,  `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` or other values of the enum. There is no need to make the window topmost afaik.

Comment: @user3518111 Have you checked [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337503/windows-7-8-screen-overlay-vc)?